# What's the proper way to code repeating CSS

Tags: css

Say throughout my site, there is multiple places that I want my text to be coloured `#f00`

If I want to target them, should I make one declaration to target everything at once e.g.

```
a, .color, h2 {
  color: #f00 
}
```

OR, should I "color" them when I am targeting them anyway e.g.

```
a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #f00;
}

.color {
  background: #333;
  color: #f00;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f00;
}
```

I'm never sure which to do, sure, the first part in this isntance looks like less code, but then I am referencing tags more than I need to. But on the other hand, I am using `color: #f00` 3 times instead of just the once.

I appreciate neither are "wrong", I was just wondering if one is quicker, more semantic or what.

Note: This isn't my code in any site, just a quick mock up. I'm looking for an answer on a bigger scale

Comment: Use the second form if you expect the color to change.  Use the first form if you don't.

Comment: Not having directly to do with your question, but still, you might want to have a look at Sass http://sass-lang.com/ or Less http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is the preferred method. Typically, a developer's goal is to minimize CSS size to encourage faster loading. Your first example surely takes up less space as a result of combining the classes together.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is mostly a stylistic choice, but I'll tell how I approach it.

If there's something all these cases have in common that implies that they should always have the same color, then group them together.

However, if there's something they have in common, that suggests that you should perhaps give that commonality a name, and make it a class name.  Then assign the style to the class.  This is good modularity.

If it's just by chance that they have the same color, and you're likely to change one without changing the others, use the second form.

Hope's answers is true, but unless there are a huge number of styles like this I doubt that it's going to have a noticeable impact on loading time.

I haven't played with LESS yet, I wonder if it optimizes this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The first option should be the best, in the sense that if you write less code, and that if you wanna change this color into another one everywhere, you'll have a single line to change.

But finally, this is more useful to use the second method.

If you still wanna change this color everywhere, event the simpliest editor will allow you to do it easily. But if you wanna change the color of a single div, you'll need to move your code.

A good practice (using the second method), is to reference all used colors at the top of your main css file (in comments), then you can easily pick one to search/replace all matches.